# application.properties и GitHub

Tags: spring, github, spring-boot

Видно-ли будет другим пользователям GitHub'a мое имя и пароль к БД?

Comment: Да, виден. Не надо добавлять в репозиторий файлы с приватной информацией.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё, что вы выложите в публичные репозитории будет видно всем. Хорошей практикой является не выкладывать приватную информацию (логины, пароли, ключи, токены и т.п.) в репозитории, даже если это приватный репозиторий с ограниченным доступом (сегодня он доступен только для вас, а завтра вы вдруг решите открыть его всему миру).